# Linq to get complete row based on duplicate values in column

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a LINQ to use with my datatable and display all the duplicate rows based on certain columns in windows form datagrid view.

The LINQ should give a result similar to the plain old below give SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t
JOIN (  SELECT Taskid, Studentid, DateChangeid
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY Taskid, studentid, datechangeid
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) temp
  ON t.taskid = temp.taskid AND t.studentid= temp.studentid AND t.datechangeid= temp.datechangeid
```

Comment: Please never just dump SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Comment: Noted, thanks. I am very new to C#, LiNQ.  I will post detailed case for any further queries. Just added my code used for a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by writing two linq as given below.

```
var RepeatedValues = from d in DataTableitems.AsEnumerable()
            group d by d.Field<string>("MobileNo") into itemGroup
            where itemGroup.Count() > 1
            select new { name = itemGroup.Key };

var RepeatedInRows= from d in DataTableitems.AsEnumerable()
              join c in RepeatedValues.AsEnumerable() on d.Field<string>
              ("MobileNo") equals c.name
              select d;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
var result = 
 t.GroupBy(g => new {TaskId = Taskid, StudentId = studentid, DatechangeId = datechangeid})
  .Where(g => g.Count > 1)
  .ToList();
```

Now you're joining `Table1` on `Table1` which isn't needed, just do the filtering on `Table1` only.

Now the result will be of type `List<IGrouping<'a,Table1>>` though because of the anonymous keyselector, you can also define `TaskId` , `StudentId` and `DateChangeID` in  a class to get rid of that. For example:

```
public class Table1GroupKey
{
   public int TaskId {get; set;}
   public int StudentId {get; set;}
   public int DateChangeId {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can use:

```
GroupBy(g => new Table1GroupKey { ... })
```

And your result will be `List<IGrouping<Table1GroupKey,Table1>>`.

Comment: Thanks, This is listing only 3 columns used for grouping. in my case I want to get complete rows with all columns from Table1. There are more columns in in my table other than the matching columns.

Comment: @user3658516 hence the `IGrouping`. They will be grouped by `Table1GroupKey` and for every key there is a list of records of type `Table1` so you *do* have all the columns